# Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin MacOS operational issue

Tags: qgis, python, macos

I am using MacOS Big Sur. I have QGIS 3.18.x installed on my system. At another place in my office, I have Ubuntu Linux 21.04, and with QGIS 3.18.x installed. As an additional information, both the systems have Anaconda installed.

I am trying to use the Semi-Automatic classification plugin (the latest one), and it appears that it is getting stuck while doing the DOS correction. I unchecked the DOS correction checkbox and clicked `Run` and still it gets stuck. However, on the Linux machine it runs successfully.

What could be the issue?

One year earlier, the Semi Automatic Classification Plugin was working smoothly. This issue is reproducible, because I tried doing the same thing on two different Apple based computers.

**Edit**

Based on the comment received, I am attaching a screenshot which will tell you about the issue I am facing. This issue continues to be there even in QGIS 3.20.

[image: Processing stuck at 20% for more than an hour until I press Cancel]

Comment: Sounds like a curly one.  Just to clarify, what precisely does "getting stuck" mean?  Can you elaborate on this?  How far does it get.   What output (if any)?  What does it look like when it is "stuck"?  How long does it stay "stuck" before you intervene?  Etc.

Comment: Edit added - details and pictures.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? Having the same problem